# Encoder missing counts

Tags: encoder

I have a question about rotary incremental encoder, when there is a problem within an encoder, and this one misses a count:

1.if he misses a count on the A signal does the related B signal also misses the same count ?
2. Does the encoder misses the count because of noise within the A, B signal? or because of some other reason ?

[image]

Comment: Two likely problems: contact bounce and undersampling.

Comment: Another reason could be misalignment between the encoder and opto sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.if he misses a count on the A signal does the related B signal also misses the same count ?

Could be, could not be. Impossible to say!

> 2. Does the encoder misses the count because of noise within the A, B signal? or because of some other reason ?

It *could* be noise, but that  unlikely, as the output of the usual devices is a signal with significant amplitude, and hence, noise power would have to be very high for that to happen.

It's more likely that you moving to fast, and either whatever you use to look at the impulse chain is not fast enough, or your electrical setup overall has a low-pass characteristic that just "smooths" the rectangles away.

The very likely easiest way to find out is an oscilloscope.